# Using python modules over Paramiko (SSH)

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I have recently installed and used Paramiko to connect via SSH to another computer in my domain.

What I originally wanted to do was to connect and run a python module on the remote computer over SSH, but now I realise that SSH only provides limited functionality so calling the module isn't possible.

I know I can call a script on the remote server and run that as a way of getting around this problem, but I was not sure about the security implications of doing this. Also, of getting a result from the script. At the moment I am looking for the result using a print statement from the script and looking at it by reading the lines from stdout.

eg

```
If x:
    print "Yes"
else:
    print "No"
```

which I then read in via SSH and look at what the result is. Is this a stupid way of doing it or am I missing a much more obvious / better way of knowing what the result is from my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something simple, your method works fine.  If you need something more complex, you might want to look at something that lets you do `RMI`, like [Pyro](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pyro4).

Comment: Thanks, came across someone at work who knew about this stuff and he gave a largely similar answer.